# How know what theme/theme name a Drupal site is using?

Tags: theming

Like in Wordpress, we can know what theme name a site is using by look at the page source and it will show something like

```
wp-content/theme/theme-name
```

Well, how we can know what theme a Drupal site is using? I try to look at the page source of a Drupal site but i cannot figure out what theme or theme name the site is using.

Is there any trick to unlock this?

Comment: you can find it if you are logged in as `Admin` (uid=1), by visiting `http://yoursite/admin/appearance` and look for the list of themes; the theme which is active has "(default theme)" written after its name.

Comment: Forgot to state that i cannot login to as admin because its not my site, if its mine, i probably didn't ask this question

Comment: It may be made impossible. It's relatively easy to obscure for sure.

Answer (score 8):

You can get it from source of any page. Have a look for the javascript array at the top/bottom of the page that begins with:

```
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {...
```

There's a setting in that array called "theme" which contains the name of the theme being used for that page.

Comment: +1 it works! I found this
`jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, {"basePath":"\/site05\/","pathPrefix":"","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"bartik"...`

Comment: I cannot find it, try, i am trying to get the theme name of http://www.sapurakencana.com/.

Comment: Erm...the site you linked to isn't a Drupal site

Comment: Then what is it? its because when i put /admin there is a login page for admin

Comment: No idea but it's definitely not a Drupal site

Comment: /admin is not a sign that you're on a Drupal site.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar in Drupal (by default).

Look for

> /sites/default/themes/THEMENAME

or

> /sites/all/themes/THEMENAME

But there are ways to rename / remap those standard folders to hide singns for Drupal.

Comment: I cannot find it, try, i am trying to get the theme name of this site: http://bit.ly/MhKQji

Comment: I think this is not a Drupal site at all. You can also check with /user or /admin or /node to see if its a drupal page.

Comment: Then what is it? its because when i put /admin there is a login page for admin

Comment: Dont know. Not Drupal :-) If you need to know it (for whatever reason) then ask the sit owner.

Comment: You can use Builtwith to determine what a site is based on, i.e., http://builtwith.com/sapurakencana.com In this case, other than CodeIgniter, it does not appear to identify a specific CMS, but does provide other stack info.

Answer (score -1):

Just right-click on the drupal logo image or any Drupal site's logo image that appears at the top, and select "Inspect element". In the src of the image the name following "themes/" is the name of current theme; e.g. `http://sitename.com/themes/bartik/logo.png` then bartik is the current theme.

Comment: That won't work...if you upload a custom logo using the theme settings the path will change to the public file path, and won't contain the name of the theme any more.

Comment: I cannot find it, try, i am trying to get the theme name of this site: http://bit.ly/MhKQji